# Change bot avatar only in specific guilds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**I'm trying to make a multi-guild bot and I'm struggling with making a command that changes the bot avatar only for the guild where the command was executed!**

**I tried to make a DISCORD API call to change the bot user avatar but I ended by changing the avatar for all guilds.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do that. Bots don't have access to some user functionalities like blocking someone, joining a server without a moderator's will and, in this case, change it's avatar/username depending on a server. An alternative is to create a webhook. You can change (with the necessary permissions) it's avatar and username at free will and it can send messages, embeds, files etc.. there's a [full guide on discord.js webhooks](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/webhooks.html#what-is-a-webhook) if you want.